# The value is not inserting in database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create an API for registration with OTP verification. The OTP is successfully sent on mobile. But the value of users is not inserted in the database. Here is my signup code.

**signup.php**

```
<?php

include('config.php');

if( !empty($_POST['name']) && 
    !empty($_POST['mobile']) && 
    !empty($_POST['email']) && 
    !empty($_POST['password'])
  ){
        
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $str = mt_rand(100000, 999999); 
    
    $avalible_user_name="";
    $avalible_user_email="";
    
    $SQL= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  users WHERE mobile='".$mobile."' ");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($SQL)){
        $avalible_user_name=$row['mobile'];
    }
    $SQL= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  users WHERE email='".$email."' ");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($SQL)){
        $avalible_user_email=$row['email'];
    }   
        if($avalible_user_name=="" && $avalible_user_email==""){                
                    $SQLQUERY = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users SET 
                                            name = '" . $name."',
                                            mobile = '" . $mobile."',
                                            email = '" . $email."',
                                            password = '" . md5($password)."',
                                            otp = '".$str."',
                                            status = 0 ");
                                                            
                                            
                                        
                    $msg = "Your verification code:".$str.".";
                    $sms_text = str_replace(" ","%20",$msg);
                    $api_key = '2584909553545C';
                    $from = 'chkotp';
                    $api_url = "**My otp url**";
                    $response = file_get_contents($api_url);
                                    
                    die(json_encode(array("success"=>"true","message"=>"OTP sent to your mobile number please verify.")));                          
        }else{
             die(json_encode(array("success"=>"false","message"=>"Mobile or email all ready exits ")));
        }
}else{
         die(json_encode(array("success"=>"false","message"=>"Empty Parameters..!!")));
}
?>
```

Comment: Too many tags with no supportive code and the mysqli tag is questionable as to the api used here.

Comment: use mysqli or pdo instead of mysql

Comment: Yeah, and you have add connection to mysql-query funcion.

Comment: That's quite a lot of possible SQL injection vulnerabilities you have there... **Never ever insert (user)data into queries directly!** You should immediately drop the usage of the deprecated `mysql` extension, switch to PDO, and start using [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)!

Answer (score -1):

Your insert query syntax is wrong,

```
$new_pass = md5($password);
$SQLQUERY = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users( name, mobile, email, password) values('$name','$mobile','$email','$new_pass')");
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: What happend bro ?? you not like query?? 
or you are here for only decrese votes of others

Comment: Thaks to your reply but it did not helped me.

Comment: its fine but why you giving minus votes to all the answers its not helped you but its not wrong please check in any sites.
if the answer is not helpfull to you, you can not give all the answers minus votes.

Comment: Bro I did  not given any minus votes the vote is given by other developers.